responsive design on my social icons hover effect
Kindly set your browser to responsive design at a width of 490px for these effect.
I'm trying to make my social icons to remain at the same position when I hover over them. For the first top social icons,  when i hover over them, the bottom icons tend to move down. I would like to prevent this and only have them moving down without affecting the other social icons below. I used a padding-top:10px to move down the icons when. Also i am using boxicons.


#contact {
  background-color: #303841;
  padding: 140px 0 120px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 70vh;
  /*specifying the height ensures no change even when paddding-top/bottom*/
  /* border: 2px solid blue; */
}

#contact h1 {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  color: var(--white-col);
  font-size: 3.125rem;
}

.dots {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: var(--white-col);
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#contact p {
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-style: italic;
  color: var(--white-col);
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.social-icons {
  /* border:2px solid red; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 2rem;
  padding: 20px 0;
  /* margin-bottom: 50px; */
}

.social-icons i {
  /* border:2px solid black; */
  display: inline-block;
  color: var(--white-col);
  font-size: 23px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.social-icons i:hover {
  transform: translateY(10px);
  transition: ease-in-out;
  transition-duration: 0.90s;
}

footer {
  border-top: 3px solid rgb( 231, 76, 60);
  padding: 25px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #303841;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/portfolio.css">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300..800;1,300..800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
  <section id="contact">
    <h1>Let's work together
      <div class="dots"></div>
      <div class="dots"></div>
      <div class="dots"></div>
    </h1>
    <p>How do you take your coffee?</p>
    <div class="social-icons">
      <i class='bx bxl-facebook-square'> Facebook</i>
      <i class='bx bxl-github'> Github</i>
      <i class='bx bxl-twitter'> Twitter</i>
      <i class='bx bxl-gmail'> Send a Mail</i>
      <i class='bx bxs-phone-call'> Call me</i>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <p>Made by <i class='bx bxs-heart'></i> Dreamer </p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>




please provide a codepen for this

@JayendraAwasthi how do i provide a codepen for my code. I'm very new to this stuff.

Please don't use codepen or any other external site for your code but make a runnable snippet in your question using the <> feature in the edit facility.

If you use a transformation rather than a change of padding then other elements will not be affected. eg. transform: translateY(10px);

all you have to do is using transform: traslate(), in your case you can:
transform: translateY(20px)

Hope I helped ^_^
